# bootstrap modal window dynamic width with max value?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal window that I need to dynamically size based off of the content being displayed, at max height and width of 95%, with auto overflow for scroll bars. I'm a total beginner with CSS, so bear with me if I'm doing something completely wrong/idiotic.

The height works great, it dynamically sizes and if it hits max, it overflows w/ scroll bar. The width I just cannot get to work. I can either get it to fill the whole page, or stay small, but cannot get it to size dynamically. I know it's bad practice to put styles inline, but I am doing it as a one off for this page only.

My Bootstrap modal:

```
    <div class=modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex=-1 role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;max-height:1000px;max-width:95%;">
                     ... close all the above tags w/o anything but standard div/span for modal message and footer
```

I think the issue is that bootstrap modals have a default width value that I don't think I can override (based on size, like default, modal-sm, or modal-lg). Any clue how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize the height and width of the modal based on content in the following way--

**working example**

```css
 .modal-dialog{
    position: relative;
    display: table; 
    overflow-y: auto;    
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 300px;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

           </head>
<body >
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> 
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex=-1 role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>close all the above tags w/o anything but standard div/span for modal message and footer............................................................................................................................................................................................</p>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, this does dynamically size the modal window, but the overflow doesn't seem to be working. The modal will expand beyond the height and width of the page still. I've tried adding max-height and max-width, but the content inside the modal gets sized incorrectly then.

Comment: I was able to get this to be 'close enough' by setting width on .modal